# Doubt in understanding -Closed sets of compact metric spaces are compact

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

We know that closed subsets of compact metric spaces are compact.I know the rigorous proof.Somehow the picture is not clear to me. Why is any subset of a compact metric space not compact?I know it is not , by taking an example .However if someone could guide me as to what will be the picture behind it(Taking open covers as open balls covering the metric space).I know this may sound stupid but I am very new to the concept , rigorous proofs are not helping me to understand the concepts.

Comment: Perhaps you can add some thoughts as to why you might expect an arbitrary subset of a compact space to be compact. This would help in identifying any underlying misunderstanding of concepts, etc. (Not a stupid question btw.)

Comment: For now, all I can say is that if you take an arbitrary subset $X$ of a compact space $C$, then there may be all kinds of open covers of $X$ that are *not* open covers of $C$ (and can't be extending in a nice way to an open cover of $C$). So compactness of $C$ may offer no help in getting a finite subcover of $X$, without knowing more about $X$.

Comment: In particular, if I know $X$ is closed then I can extend any open cover $\mathcal{U}$ of $X$ to an open cover $\mathcal{U}'$ of $C$ by throwing in $C\setminus X$, which is an *open* set by the assumption that $X$ is closed. So $\mathcal{U}'=\mathcal{U}\cup\{C\setminus X\}$. Since $C$ is compact, we know some finite subset of $\mathcal{U}'$ covers $C$, and removing $C\setminus X$ gives us a finite subset of $\mathcal{U}$ that covers $X$.